# .NET RichTextBox Tab Character

Tags: .net, winforms, richtextbox

I'm using a RichTextBox control in a .NET Windows Form application.  I allow users to press the TAB key within the textbox itself.  However when I save the .Text value in the textbox it will show up like this:

```
"This[]is[a]tab[]test[]"
```

Where each time the user pressed TAB, it shows up as unrecognized characters in the .Text property.

What's going on here?

Example Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "unrecognized characters"? The ASCII value for TAB is 8. It may be inserting char(8)'s in there.

Comment: @RoyDictus .Text should show an escaped value; _\t_

Comment: Basically if I typed this into the RichTextBox: "Hi[tab key press]My name is John Doe".  When I check the .Text property of the RichTextBox it shows this as the value "Hi[]My name is John Doe".  It's like it doesn't recognize the TAB character when I press it.  It just shows a square instead.  I'll attach a screenshot shortly.

Comment: @RoyDictus I think TAB is 9.  BACKSPACE is 8.  [See ASCI Character Set](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html)

Comment: @LarsTech: You are right, of course. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up searching for all instances of a 'TAB' character being pressed and replacing it with a '\t' and that worked:

```
Dim tabString = Convert.ToChar("    ") //This is the [] string
RichTextBox.Text = RichTextBox.Text.Replace(tabString, "     ")
```

Not the best solution, still do not understand why the RichTextBox isn't picking up on the TAB key automatically but it works for now.

Answer (score 2):

In the Intermediate Window:

?RichTextBox1.Text results in `"Hi mint "` even though with `AcceptTab=True` we think it should be `"Hi[TAB Key]Mint"`

?RichTextBox1.Rtf results in

```
"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 Hi\tab mint\tab\par  }"
```

Here is the trick I believe your looking for:

```
RichTextBox1.SaveFile("C:\abc.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText)
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this.  Though this is not really ideal since a user will be saving multiple times and I'd hate to have to write a text file every time they save.  But it's worth trying

Answer (score 0):

There is a property in RichTextBox called "AcceptsTab", just set this property as "true".